# How to perform correct select over unixtimestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, timestamp, timezone

I have table with UNIX sql time stamp like `1615582447` in `receivedOn`.

I am not sure, how to work with this timestamp in case of some interval.

What is the correct way how to perform sql according to **user timezone**?

My current code is (for `Europe/Prague` timezone):

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(receivedOn) > ("2021-03-07T23:00:00.000Z") AND FROM_UNIXTIME(receivedOn) < ("2021-03-2021-03-08T22:59:59.999Z")
```

But this select return data outside interval.

What is the correct way or...better?

Comment: from_uNixtimetstamdp return ´2021-03-12 21:54:07` so the comaprison needs a mysltime in the same form

Answer (score 0):

this can#t work in that form, as you have no correct mysql time to compare it with

```
 SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1615582447 ) > CONVERT("2021-03-07T23:00:00.000Z", datETIME)
```

returns true or 1

you should always use mysql conform dates and time, to use in your query, and let the programming language convert it into the right form